# How to group form when using asp.net mvc on a View?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am struggling to align my button, the one that pulls data as excel to be closer to upload button on the same near its position. extract button is below the upload and it does not look good. It has its own built in method that calls a different controller and method. How can i achieve this on bootstrap?

```
//View
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Browse", "Week", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "upload" }))
    {


        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", routeValues: new { }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "modal-link btn btn-primary" })



        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="upload" class="btn-primary" required style="display:none;" />
        <label for="fileUpload" id="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</label>
        }
<p>
    <!--Extraction list button to pull out data as Excel format-->
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportToExcel", "Week", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    <input type="submit" value="Extract" formaction="ExportToExcel" class="btn btn-primary" />
    }

//Controller
   public void ExportToExcel()
        {

            var v = new GridView();
            v.DataSource = this.GetExtractionViewModels();
            v.DataBind();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExtractionRecords.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);
            v.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
            Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            //return View("DataResult");
        }
```

[image]

Comment: A picture or screenshot will help us understand what you're trying to accomplish. But a solution will probably involve adjusting css styling to change the spacing. Have you tried adjusting the margin or padding?

Comment: @Jasen i have attached the picture, thanks

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the CSS properties for margin and padding?